# Maple tree disease with pics this time

Tags: trees, diseases, maple

These fluffy things are only visible in early morning.I got a good close up and notice tiny bugs in the web[image: close up]I can't seem to add 2 images so I will post another question with the tree image

Comment: You can now upload a new picture here because I have upvoted both your questions so that you have the minimum 10 points necessary for multiple upload. You don't have to post a new question. I hope some one will help identify the problem of your tree.

Comment: @pnuts Let me tell you how the system is supposed to work: new users can't post multiple images unless they have a minimum rep because this is easiest way to sort out spammers. Since the OP has an on-topic question that is not spam or abusive, I follow the spirit of the rule, not only its letter. You are free to understand the rules differently. :)